# ¿Porqué recibo este error "APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE" de la librería python-binance?

Tags: python, binance

He creado un bot de arbitraje triangular con el lenguaje de programación Python para operar en Binance desde un VPS.

Tengo comprado BTC, que es la moneda con la que quiero operar, en concreto un total de "0.00278926".
También tengo una lista de varios tokens para hacer el arbitraje triangular.

Imagínense que el bot ha encontrado una oportunidad de Arbitraje con estos pares:
`['BNBBTC', 'ADABNB', 'ADABTC']`
Obviamente, el bot debería de comprar con BTC una cantidad de BNB, luego con BNB compraría ADA y luego vendería ADA a BTC. Hasta entonces bien.

Sin embargo, cuando encuentra esa oportunidad e intenta comprar, el bot me manda este error en la consola:

`APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE`

Y he revisado con anterioridad a ver si la cantidad mínima para comprar BNB con BTC era más grande de lo que yo tenía y no es así, tengo cantidad entre el mínimo y el máximo.

Este es mi código una vez que la oportunidad de arbitraje (descontando los fees) nos vaya a aportar beneficio:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
import time
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from binance_key import BinanceKey
import json

"""
... Aquí va el código de las Key, la inicialización del bot, etc.
"""

list_of_arb_sym = [
            ['BNBBTC', 'ADABNB', 'ADABTC'],         #Comprando BNB
            ['BNBBTC', 'AAVEBNB', 'AAVEBTC'],
            ['...'] #Imaginaros que hay una lista de 300 pares

#Luego me he encargado de pasar los valores de una linea de la lista a list_of_sym[0], list_of_sym[1], list_of_sym[2] pero no lo añado para que no sea excesivamente largo
"""
... aquí iría ese código
"""

#Recoger valores y precio
price_order_1 = client.get_avg_price(symbol=list_of_sym[0])
price_order_2 = client.get_avg_price(symbol=list_of_sym[1])
price_order_3 = client.get_avg_price(symbol=list_of_sym[2])

price1 = float(price_order_1["price"])
price2 = float(price_order_2["price"])
price3 = float(price_order_3["price"])

"""
... más código irrelevante y que funciona
"""

if arb_opportunity == 'Yes':
    place_order_msg = "REALIZANDO OPERACIÓN\n\n"
    print(place_order_msg)
    data_log_to_file(place_order_msg)

    #Primera Compra
    balance1 = client.get_asset_balance('BTC')
    quantity1 = (float(balance1['free'])/price1)
    quantity_1 = round(quantity1, 5)
    
    
    order_1 = client.order_market_buy(
        symbol=list_of_sym[0],
        quantity=quantity_1)
    
    first_order = "Primera operación realizada.\n\n"
    print(first_order)
    data_log_to_file(first_order)

    #Segunda compra
    simbolo2 =list_of_sym[0]
    simbolo2form = simbolo2[0:3]
    balance2 = client.get_asset_balance(simbolo2form)
    quantity2 = (float(balance2['free'])/price2)
    quantity_2 = round(quantity2, 5)
    
    order_2 = client.order_market_buy(
        symbol=list_of_sym[1],
        quantity=quantity_2)

    second_order = "Segunda operación realizada.\n\n"
    print(second_order)
    data_log_to_file(second_order)

    #Venta y última operación
    simbolo3 = list_of_sym[1]
    simbolo3form = simbolo3[0:-3]
    balance3 = client.get_asset_balance(simbolo3form)
    quantity3 = (float(balance3['free'])/price3)
    quantity_3 = round(quantity3, 5)

    order_3 = client.order_market_sell(
        symbol=list_of_sym[2],
        quantity=quantity_3)
    

    third_order = "Operación de venta realizada. \n\n"
    third_order += "EL BOT HA COMPRADO!"
    print(third_order)
    data_log_to_file(third_order)
```

No se como solucionarlo, creo que he hecho todo el tiempo lo correcto ya que cuando cambié la 'quantity' en el primer 'order_market_buy' a 0.26, compró sin problemas.

Comment: valida los datos que le estan enviado o el contenido de Lot_Size

Comment: La cantidad que tengo es superior del min y inferior del max de Lot_Size

Comment: Creo que puede funcionar teniendo en cuenta el stepSize, y restandole la comision del 0.1%. Estoy programando el mismo bot de arbitraje triangular.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en que redondeas a 5 decimales, cada tick tiene una presición máxima, que puedes checar en exchange.info, si le pasas una presición (por ejemplo a ADA que supere la presición del sistema te mandaría ese error) puedes corregirlo usando una presición a cada ticker y luego  round.
La otra es que cheques la presicion del tick, esto se puede hacer desde la API.

```
info=client.exchange_info() 
b=info['symbols'] 
c=[] 
for a in b: 
    dato=a['symbol'], a['pricePrecision'],a['quantityPrecision'] 
    c.append(dato) 
#con esto ya tenemos una lista de los simbolos y sus 
#precisiones – Edmundo García hace 1 hora
```

Comment: por ejemplo, como sería??

Comment: Mira yo uso un archivo de configuracion llamado datos.py y pongo, por ejemplo    Tick="ADABTC", presicioncantidad=4 luego importo el archivo y cuando voy a comprar en round uso cantidad=round(micantidad,datos.presicioncantidad) en mi bot así hago exactamente para solucionar ese error

Comment: Una explicación con su respectivo ejemplo siempre se aprecia y así ayudas a muchas personas.

Comment: La otra es que cheques la presicion del tick, esto se puede hacer desde la API info=client.exchange_info()
b=info['symbols']
c=[]
for a in b:
    dato=a['symbol'], a['pricePrecision'],a['quantityPrecision']
    c.append(dato)

#con esto ya tenemos una lista de los simbolos y sus precisiones

Comment: agrega eso a tu respuesta

Comment: por favor en tu respuesta edita y aumenta la solucion para que esta pueda ser marcada como correcta

Comment: Ya solucioné la pregunta. Mañana, que hoy tengo poco tiempo, publicaré la solución